# Java Stream Occurrences

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the list of following objects. Using `Stream` API, can I get a `User` with the number of frequency it appeared in the `List`?

```
public class User {
    string name;
    int age;
}
```

Comment: How do you identify a unique User? By name?

Comment: can see the list? and you want to match the user based on both params? and what do you mean by stream?

Comment: Yes by name @Eran

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo By steam I meant if I can get the solution using the java8 stream api.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `groupingBy` combined with `counting`:

```
Map<String,Long> countByName =    
    users.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName,Collectors.counting()));
```

This gives you the the count for each `User` name.

Comment: can we some how get the following results Map<User,Long>

Comment: @pannu What `User` would that be when there are multiple `User`s having the same name? You can produce a `Map<String,List<User>>` of all the `User`s grouped by name.

Comment: Yeaah that would work thanks @Eran

Comment: @pannu Then just use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName));`